# On Error for windows application

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any global event in .NET Windows Forms and WPF applications, equivalent to  On_Error in ASP.NET - Global.aspx?

Comment: Thanks Andre.  so is there any way to trace an  exception at application level in c#.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, you can use [Application.ThreadException](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/craig/archive/2004/06/13/1455.aspx)

For user friendly Exception Handling, check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx).

```
[STAThread] static void Main() {
  Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
  Application.Run(new Form1());
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  throw new Exception("Whoops"); 
}

private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e) {
  MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message); 
}
```

Comment: i am using wpf so how to got main()

Comment: sorry i though it would be same for both... i m new to WPF ... discovered there is no main().  now after googling i got to know how to add a main() but getting error becoz i also have a resource file

Answer (score 1):

```
Application.ThreadException
```

This event is raised whenever an unhandled exception occurs.

I mostly subscribe to this event, and, in the eventhandler, I log the Exception that has occured, or display a MessageBox which displays that something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options to trap unhandled exceptions globally:

- `Application.ThreadException` for `Windows.Forms` (as already pointed out by others)
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

The following sample program shows how to use the `UnhandledException` event in C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
        Console.WriteLine("Unhandled exception!!");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Application.ThreadException, you should handle AppDomain.CurrentDoman.UnhandledException. The relevant snippet from one of my program.cs files looks like this:

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(AppExceptionHandler.Application_ThreadException);
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppExceptionHandler.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

Edited to add:
Here's a [good article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-dealing-with-unhandled-exceptions) that explains further.

Answer (score 0):

For both ASP.NET and WinForms apps, there is the AppDomain UnhandledException event:

```
AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf UnhandledException
```

In this handler, you can perform any custom logging/recovery needed:

```
Private Sub UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Unhandled exception:" & vbCrLf & e.ExceptionObject.ToString)
End Sub
```

Please note that you're *not* catching or handling the exception in this case: you're only receiving a notification event. Unless you end the application in your event handler, the exception will be propagated to the higher-level fault handler, which for WinForms apps will usually be in the operating system, leading to the familiar "This application has..." crash dialog.